# Get Value from AnyObject Response Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How to get the values of id,content,name from the response from the server.
The response from the server is as an AnyObject and if I print, it appears like given below...

```
{
 content = xxxx
 id = 22
 name = yyyy
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`AnyObject` can be downcast into other types of classes, so many possibilities!

```
//if you're confident that responseObject will definitely be of this dictionary type
let name = (responseObject as! [String : AnyObject])["name"] 

//optional dictionary type
let name = (responseObject as? [String : AnyObject])?["name"] 

//or unwrapping, name will be inferred as AnyObject
if let myDictionary = responseObject as? [String : AnyObject] {
    let name = myDictionary["name"]
}

//or unwrapping, name will be inferred as String
if let myDictionary = responseObject as? [String : String] {
    let name = myDictionary["name"]
}
```

Check out [the reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html).  There's even a section on `AnyObject`